# How to restrict usual users from accessing admin area?

Tags: php, database, controls, admin

I'm trying to create a cms which has different user groups. Say admin and registered
What i want to do here is that i want only the admin to have the access to admin folder and others whether they are usual users or any other i want to restrict the access to admin folder

```
// Here is what i have in my db
tabalename.groups (id,name) values (1, 'registered),(2,'admin')
```

I am assigning these group names by giving the user a group_id but i know it does not have anything to do with the access

So How do i do that in php ??

Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: Make a row in the table to restrict or grant access to it according to the value of the usergroup he's in.

Comment: Thanks but  little detail will be appreciated plz

Comment: are you saying that i should use the header location method ???

Comment: A simple `if statement` with a check from `database column` should be just fine.

Comment: There is a header location method to tell who has access and who not?

Comment: Yess Thanks i had already done that but thought there might be a secure way

Answer (score 0):

This is one way your table could look like with an extra column `status` to denote the accessibility level of the user.

```
------------------------------
id | username    | status
1  | emkay992    | admin
2  | ayeshacutie | registered
------------------------------
```

And When logging in, compare the values from that column `status` in database and redirect through `header();` as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your ans i did had that functionality implemented just wanted to of a better way to do it .. :)